# How do I use this substitution to reduce the equation $\sec\left(x\right)\:\frac{dy}{dx}+y=y^4$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

The question:
Use substitution $z=\frac{1}{y^3}$ to reduce the equation:

$$\sec\left(x\right)\:\frac{dy}{dx}+y=y^4$$

to a linear form.

I'm stuck on whether to first divide by some function of $y$ then substitute, and how to rewrite $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $z$.

Comment: We have $y=\frac{1}{z^{1/3}}$. Use the chain rule $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1}{3}z^{-4/3}\frac{dz}{dx}$, to get $\frac{-\sec (x)}{3}\frac{dz}{dx}+z=1$.

Comment: This is Bernoulli equation.

Comment: To keep things simple just do what is said, I mean $$ z = \frac{1}{y^3} $$  $$ \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{-3}{y^4} \, \frac{dy}{dx} $$ Now divide the given differential equation by $y^4$ and you're done.....

Answer (score 0):

> "...and how to rewrite $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $z$."

For the substitution $z:=\frac{1}{y^3}$ (which is a substitution inspired by the ode which is Bernoulli) with chain rule one can write
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=(-\frac{3}{y^4}) \frac{dy}{dx}\leadsto \frac{dy}{dx}=(-\frac{y^4}{3})\frac{dz}{dx}.$$

> "I'm stuck on whether to first divide by some function of y
> then substitute..."

Yes, you "first divide for $y^4$" in the ode to obtain
$$\frac{1}{y^4}\sec(x)y'+\frac{1}{y^4}y=\frac{y^4}{y^4},\quad y\not=0$$
Then return to the substitution and one can write
$$\frac{1}{y^4}\sec(x)(-\frac{y^4}{3}\frac{dz}{dx})+\frac{1}{y^4}y=1\leadsto-\frac{\sec x}{3}\frac{dz}{dx}+z=1$$
Then you can re-write it as
$$\frac{dz}{dx}-3\cos(x)z=\cos(x),\quad \cos(x)\not=0$$
which is linear with general solution
$$z=1+Ae^{3\sin x}\leadsto \frac{1}{y^3}=1+Ae^{3\sin x}$$

NB: I suppose that the problem is to work on the substitution, in any case it does not hurt to comment that your ode is separable from the beginning
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(x)(y^4-y)$$
Then integrating give the answer.